# Print raw field data

Tags: 7, entities

I have a long text (plain text) field connected to my content type. The field contains plain html code.

Is it possible to print this field without sanitizing it's content. I mean raw html output of it's content.

And the main thing is to do that without coding, just from admin area. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it without coding from the admin area.(Disclaimer: a bit hacky).

Go to the "admin/config/content/formats" area and disable all the filter formats except "Plain Text".

Go to your content type display settings tab and change the format in the dropdown to "Default" and save the settings.

If you view your node now, you will be able to see its raw content form without all the sanitation.